# Trac tickets have file reference

Tags: git, ubuntu, trac

I am a trac newbie. I would like to make my trac tickets have automatic references to change-sets in my git repository.

I.e. if i commit with

```
git commit -m "Refs #1 - some commit" .
```

I would like for the ticket itself to show the changeset that was committed at "."

Currently, following these instructions:
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/Ubuntu-10.04.03-Git

For the individual files, it does show the ticket number that was referenced. It seems like it would be easy to make the reverse also true.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to enable [CommitTicketUpdater](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater) and setup [explicit synchronization](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Git).

Comment: In case everything seems to be installed properly, look at the trac log file (after you've switched on logging level "DEBUG"). Then Trac's source files `trac/versioncontrol/api.py` and `tracopt/ticket/commit_updater.py` write some logging.